# Commit Error in 'git'

Tags: git

Even though i have uninstalled Edit Plus named Folder in my program files,it it showing the same error while using 'Git Commit'.

***$ git commit 'C:\Program Files\EditPlus': C:\Program Files\EditPlus: No such file or directory error: There was a problem with the editor ''C:\Program Files\EditPlus***

Comment: Are you trying to commit using the EditPlus editor?  That would imply that it's still alive and kicking.

Comment: Thank you Tim,i have installed edit plus in my local system previously and trail was expired,so i have Uninstalled it.

Answer (score 0):

Check what have you configured as your git editor:

`git config <--global> --get core.editor`

Set to some existing text editor of your choice:

`git config <--global> --set core.editor <path of the editor>`